# Form isn't validating despite having a csrf token

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I have seen a few similar questions here, but none of the solutions seem to apply here(the problem is usually that it lacks a csrf token, which is not the case here).

I have a form with four fields- 3 drop down lists with SelectField and one StringField- built using flask wtforms. I tried adding an edit feature to this, which uses the same HTML template, but this it isn't getting validated(not entering the form.validate_on_submit section). This is the code for the function:

```py
@app.route('/movements/<int:movement_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def edit_movement(movement_id):
    movement = Movement.query.get_or_404(movement_id)
    form = MovementForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product = Product.query.filter_by(id=form.product.data).first()
        from_location = Location.query.filter_by(id=form.from_location.data).first()
        to_location = Location.query.filter_by(id=form.to_location.data).first()
        if int((Balance.query.filter_by(product = product.name).filter_by(location = from_location.name).first()).balance) < int(form.quantity.data) and from_location.name != "":
           flash("Invalid movement. Quantity of the product is insufficient.")
        else: 
            movement.product_id = product.id
            movement.product = product.name
            movement.from_location_id = from_location.id
            movement.from_location = from_location.name
            movement.to_location_id = to_location.id
            movement.to_location = to_location.name
            movement.quantity = form.quantity.data
            db.session.commit()
            flash('The product movement has been edited!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('movements'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.product.choices = [(product.id,product.name) for product in Product.query.all()]
        form.from_location.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
        form.to_location.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
        form.quantity.data = movement.quantity
    edit_button = True   
    return render_template('movements.html',form=form, edit_button=edit_button)
```

This is the code for the form:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    product = SelectField("Product", choices = [])
    from_location = SelectField("From Location", choices = [], coerce=int)
    to_location = SelectField("To Location", choices = [], coerce=int)
    quantity = StringField("Quantity", validators=[DataRequired()])
    add_movement = SubmitField("Add Movement")
```

And this is the model for the table:

```
class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    product = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    from_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    to_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

The HTML code for the form:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.product.label }}
        {{ form.product }}
        {{ form.from_location.label }}
        {{ form.from_location }}
        {{ form.to_location.label }}
        {{ form.to_location }}
        {{ form.quantity.label }}
        {{ form.quantity }}
        {% if edit_button %}
            <input type="submit" value="Edit Movement">
        {% else %}
            {{ form.add_movement }}
        {% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure why my form wasn't validating, but my function started working after I replaced `if form.validate_on_submit()` with `if request.method == 'POST'`.

Answer (score 1):

`validate_on_submit` is a convenient function that combines a check for whether the form was submitted (i.e., a POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE) with call to `form.validate`. If validation fails, the dictionary held by`form.errors` will get populated with useful information.

A useful step to debug your problem would be to log (print) the contents of `form.errors` if `validate_on_submit` returns False.

Comment: ```{'product': ['Not a valid choice'], 'from_location': ['Not a valid choice'], 'to_location': ['Not a valid choice']}```- this is what ```form.errors``` yields, so clearly the problem is with the ```SubmitField``` options. Would you happen to know what's wrong with them?

Comment: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/ says "Note that the choices keyword is only evaluated once, so if you want to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices list to the field after instantiation." That suggests removing `choices = []`

Answer (score 1):

The `form.errors` in your code is as follows:

```
{'product': ['Not a valid choice'], 'from_location': ['Not a valid choice'], 'to_location': ['Not a valid choice']}
```

So it is reasonable for the `validate_on_submit` to return `False`.

If you comment out these fields and leave only the quantity it should work. The following changes worked for me and I managed to update the quantity in the DB. If it works also for you then you could try to uncomment each field and debug further.

Change the form to:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
quantity = StringField("Quantity", validators=[DataRequired()])
add_movement = SubmitField("Add Movement")
```

and the route to:

```
@app.route('/movements/<int:movement_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_movement(movement_id):
movement = Movement.query.get_or_404(movement_id)
form = MovementForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    movement.quantity = form.quantity.data
    db.session.commit()
    flash('The product movement has been edited!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('movements'))
elif request.method == 'GET':
    form.quantity.data = movement.quantity
print(form.errors)
edit_button = True
return render_template('movements.html', form=form, edit_button=edit_button)
```

Change the template to:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.quantity.label }}
    {{ form.quantity }}
    {% if edit_button %}
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Movement">
    {% else %}
        {{ form.add_movement }}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

**Update:**

The issue you are facing is described [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/7174657746/).

Please try the following and if it works as expected then set similarly the remaining fields (it worked for me and I managed to update the quantity and the from_location/id in the DB):

the form:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
fromloc = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
from_location_id = SelectField("From Location ID", choices = fromloc, coerce=int)
quantity = StringField("Quantity", validators=[DataRequired()])
add_movement = SubmitField("Add Movement")
```

the route:

```
@app.route('/movements/<int:movement_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_movement(movement_id):
    movement = Movement.query.get_or_404(movement_id)
    form = MovementForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        movement.from_location_id = form.from_location_id.data
        movement.from_location = (Location.query.filter_by(id = form.from_location_id.data).first()).name
        movement.quantity = form.quantity.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('The product movement has been edited!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('movements'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.from_location_id.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
        form.quantity.data = movement.quantity
    print(form.errors)
    edit_button = True
    return render_template('movements.html', form=form, edit_button=edit_button)
```

the template:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.from_location_id.label }}
    {{ form.from_location_id }}
    {{ form.quantity.label }}
    {{ form.quantity }}
    {% if edit_button %}
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Movement">
    {% else %}
        {{ form.add_movement }}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: But I need to be able to edit all the fields. But thank you though, now I know the problem is with editing SelectFields.